# Replace values in df1 with values from another dataset (df2)

Tags: r, replace, merge, dplyr

This is the question:

** `df1` ==> You have one dataset:

with `df1$IDs` from 1:100, (each ID appears twice `df$visit`), a column called `df1$weight` and a column called `df1$height`

** `df2`==> another dataset:

with `df2$IDs` from 1:50 (each ID appears twice `df$visit`), and a column called `df2$weight.`

And you want to create a **THIRD dataset** where you will have:

exactly the same dataset as in `df1` but for those IDs that are present in `df2` you replace `df1$weight` for `df2$weight`. Obviously taking into account visit.

How would you do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may do a join

```
library(data.table)
df3 <- copy(df1)
setDT(df3)[df2, weight := i.weight, on = .(IDs)]
```

If it is more than one column, we may do

```
setDT(df3)[df2, c('weight1', 'weight2') := .(i.weight1, i.weight2), on = .(IDs)]
```

---

If there are many columns, create an vector of those column names

```
nm1 <- names(df2)[1:5] # suppose if the first five column names wanted
nm2 <- paste0("i.", nm1) # for the corresponding column names from second data
setDT(df3)[df2, (nm1) := mget(nm2), on = .(IDs)]
```

Comment: How would you ammend that code if you'd need to substitute more than one column? (thanks so much for the answer!!)

Comment: @Lilli does the update helps

Comment: so! that is perfect! but there is only one thing that I forgot to add. And it is that it should be on= IDs and on=visit (as each patient has visit  A and B). - could you help me on this? (and then will be perfect!!) - I will amend the post!

Comment: @Lili You need `on = .(IDs, visit)`

Comment: works perfectly! - thanks so much!!!

Comment: the vector also works great! - thanks